# PHP: Saving foreach data within foreach

Tags: php, yii, foreach

I am trying to save sets of data, through these models.

Model 1:  Service

Generates a series of service dates.

Model 2:  Response

For each service entry, user is required to add a set number of responses.

So, I'd like to save multiple service entries for multiple response.  The code is fairly self explanatory, but I can add more information if required.  I can't find an easy solution to do this, though I feel it's fairly straight forward.

```
    if (isset($_POST['Service'], $_POST['Response']))
    {

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Service'];
        $valid = $model->validate();
        // date manipulation
        $start = new DateTime($model->date_booked);
        $start->format('Y-m-d');
        $end = new DateTime($model->end_date);
        $end->format('Y-m-d');
        $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($model->interval);
        $range = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

        if ($valid)
        {
            foreach ($range as $key => $value)
            {
                $schedule = new Service;
                $schedule->attributes = $_POST['Service'];
                $schedule->date_booked = $value->format('Y-m-d');
                // If I were to save here, the following, Response Model
                // will not be validated!
                // $schedule->save(); 


                foreach ($_POST['Response'] as $j => $k)
                {
                        $response[$j] = new Response;
                        $response[$j]->attributes = $_POST['Response'][$j];
                        // If I were to save the Service Models here, 
                        // evidently, entries are doubled up!
                        // $service->save();

                        $response[$j]->service_id = $service->id;
                        $valid = $response[$j]->validate() && $valid;
                        // $response[$j]->save();


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: first of all why you are using nested foreach ? nested foreach are problematic in php. It should be better for your code to use the basic structure of for loops when you want to nested loops

Comment: @Greg, I have used foreach as I will need it to access DatePeriod.  Please advise if you know of another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to just run through, yet another foreach loop, to get this working.  Yes, I do feel like I am iterating the loops, so if someone have another elegant solution, by all means share them to me. :-)

For now, this is done.

```
    if (isset($_POST['Service'], $_POST['Response']))
    {
        // Assign and validate Service mcrypt_module_is_block_algorithm
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Service'];
        $valid = $model->validate();
        // date manipulation
        $start = new DateTime($model->date_booked);
        $start->format('Y-m-d');
        $end = new DateTime($model->end_date);
        $end->format('Y-m-d');
        $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($model->interval);
        $range = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

        // Assign and Validate Response Populated questions
        foreach ($_POST['Response'] as $j => $k)
        {
                $response[$j] = new Response('populate'); // populate scenario
                $response[$j]->attributes = $_POST['Response'][$j];
                $valid = $response[$j]->validate() && $valid;
        }

        if ($valid)
        {
            foreach ($range as $key => $value)
            {
                $schedule = new Service; // static model
                $schedule->attributes = $_POST['Service'];
                $schedule->date_booked = $value->format('Y-m-d');
                $schedule->save();

                foreach ($_POST['Response'] as $x => $y)
                {
                        $response[$x] = new Response('populate'); // populate scenario
                        $response[$x]->attributes = $_POST['Response'][$x];
                        $response[$x]->service_id = $schedule->id;
                        $response[$x]->save();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Even im facing the same problem.

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz - I didn't, I'm still using the same code, which would change when I migrate my app to Yii2. I'm in the process of planning before migration. So, I'll provide a more elegant way of doing this when I get to this area.

Comment: @Glicious- ok i still have that problem. only first for-each data is getting saved. and not the second and third for-each data. any help would be appreciated.  i mean i have for-each inside for-each.. this inside for-each data is not getting saved second time.

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz - It's difficult for me to troubleshoot, without actually seeing your code. Have you looked into "safe" attributes in your model/s? See if you are able to save the data without validation using save(false).

Comment: @Glicious- yes im doing save(false) itself. can i get your email id so that i can share code with you. or can you mail me on ssalmanriyaz@gmail.com. Thanks

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz - Best to create a question on StackOverflow, and link it as a comment? That way, even if I am not able to help you, someone else might.